# Radiation efficiency of astrophysical objects using GR

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics

The radiation efficiency $\epsilon$ of an object (for example a star or black hole) can be defined as the energy dissipated by some matter moving from infinity into a lower orbit divided by the total energy of that matter stationary at infinity ($=mc^2$).

Concretely, for non-rotating spherically symmetric objects, use the Schwarzschild metric. Assuming that all the energy is radiated away and that the matter ends up in a circular orbit (a good approximation for an accretion disk, for example), we can therefore write the efficiency as:

$$\frac{mc^2-E_{circ}}{mc^2} = 1 - \frac{1-2GM/(c^2r)}{[1-3GM/(c^2r)]^{1/2}},$$

i.e. the energy has decreased in getting the matter into a circular orbit and has been radiated away.

My question is this: where has the energy come from? My instinct is that it is from something like gravitational potential energy - in the Newtonian approximation the second term in the above equation is $GMm/2r$, which suggests to me that half the G.P.E. is converteed into K.E. and the other half is given off as radiation. However, the sources I am using appear to imply that the energy is from the *rest mass itself*, so that the *mass has decreased*. Is this correct? Surely an observer free falling with the mass would see the mass remain the same? I believe this may all be to do with a lack of concrete understanding about energy in GR.

Comment: Note that insofar there was a potential energy in GR it would add to the mass seen at infinity - in some sense it is baked in already in $mc^2$.

Comment: @AndersSandberg I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by this? Is there any chance you could expand?

Comment: @safesphere thank you, it has clarified some things for me. However, I am still unsure of what would be the mass of the infalling object if measured by an observer (say at infinity) once some of the energy has been radiated away? Has it decreased? Or is that not even a valid question to ask because you can't measure it apart from locally (assuming the infalling mass itself is small enough to have a totally negligible gravitational effect on other mass). If that is the case,, what is the local measurement?

Comment: The difference between my question and the one you have referred me to is that in that question the mass falls inwards and hence a Newtonian-like 'KE gained = GPE lost' and the internal energy (identified as the mass energy) does not change. But here the GPE lost does NOT equal the KE gained, since it moves into a circular orbit. So it is more like E_internal + KE + GPE + energy radiated away is constant. But which term does the last term increase from, the first or third? If the distinction does not exist, as seems to be suggested, then surely the Newtonian argument doesn't work in this case?

Comment: Thanks @safesphere